# Bad JSON escape sequence when deserializing Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am using the below C# code to deserialize a string to an object inside azure function.

```
string jsonMessage = "{\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"filePath\",\"value\":\"\\\\\\\inv.abcas.vdi.com\\\\dev\\\\folder\\\\filename.xml\"}]}"

Message message =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(jsonMessage);
```

Its throwing an error

> Bad JSON escape sequence: \d. Path 'parameters[0].value', line 1.

Technology: .Net core 3.1, Azure function

Please help how to rectify this

Comment: Your message class is not correct. Add your message class code to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing \ before inv.abcas...

Try this,

```
string jsonMessage = "{\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"filePath\",\"value\":\"\\\\\\\\inv.abcas.vdi.com\\\\dev\\\\folder\\\\filename.xml\"}]}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage);
```